# How to update the shape, chunks and chunksize metadata of a dask array with nan dimensions

Tags: python, dask

Suppose I generate an array with a shape that depends on some computation, such as:

```
>>> import dask.array as da
>>> a = da.random.normal(size=(int(1e6), 10))
>>> a = a[a.mean(axis=1) > 0]
>>> a.shape
(nan, 10)
>>> a.chunks
((nan, nan, nan, nan, nan), (10,))
>>> a.chunksize
(nan, 10)
```

The `nan` are expected. When I persist the result of the computation on the dask workers, I would assume that this missing metadata could have been retrieved but apparently this is not the case:

```
>>> a_persisted = a.persist()
>>> a_persisted.chunks
((nan, nan, nan, nan, nan), (10,))
>>> a_persisted.chunksize
(nan, 10)
>>> a_persisted.shape
(nan, 10)
```

If I try to force a rechunk I get:

```
>>> a_persisted.rechunk("auto")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-26-31162de022a0>", line 1, in <module>
    a_persisted.rechunk("auto")
  File "/home/ogrisel/code/dask/dask/array/core.py", line 1647, in rechunk
    return rechunk(self, chunks, threshold, block_size_limit)
  File "/home/ogrisel/code/dask/dask/array/rechunk.py", line 226, in rechunk
    dtype=x.dtype, previous_chunks=x.chunks)
  File "/home/ogrisel/code/dask/dask/array/core.py", line 1872, in normalize_chunks
    chunks = auto_chunks(chunks, shape, limit, dtype, previous_chunks)
  File "/home/ogrisel/code/dask/dask/array/core.py", line 1949, in auto_chunks
    raise ValueError("Can not perform automatic rechunking with unknown "
ValueError: Can not perform automatic rechunking with unknown (nan) chunk sizes
```

What is the idiomatic way to update the metadata of my array with the actual size of the chunks that have already been computed on the worker?

I can compute them very cheaply with:

```
>>> dask.compute([chunk.shape for chunk in a_persisted.to_delayed().ravel()])
([(100108, 10), (99944, 10), (99545, 10), (99826, 10), (100099, 10)],)
```

My question is how to get a new dask array backed by the same chunks with some informative  `.shape`, `.chunk` and `.chunksize` attributes (with no nans).

```
>>> dask.__version__
'1.1.0+9.gb1fef05'
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like this will soon be solved internally in dask array (https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/3293). Until then, here is the workaround I use:

```
import dask.array as da
import dask.dataframe as dd
a = da.random.normal(size=(int(1e6), 10))
a = dd.from_dask_array(a[a.mean(axis=1) >0],columns=np.arange(a.shape[1])).to_dask_array(lengths=True).persist()
print(a.chunks)
print(a.shape)

((100068, 100157, 100279, 100446, 99706), (10,))
(500656, 10)
```

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a good solution to this today, but there could be.  I recommend raising an issue if one doesn't exist already.  This is a commonly requested feature.

Edit: this is tracked here: https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/3293

Comment: Thanks, I was too slow to follow up.

Comment: This was recently fixed by https://github.com/dask/dask/pull/5312.
y.compute_chunksizes()